# Priority queue in python with duplicate keys

Tags: python, priority-queue

I have following scenario -

```
In [2]: from heapq import heappush, heappop

In [3]: pq =[]

In [4]: heappush(pq, (2, "I hate sth"))

In [5]: heappush(pq, (2, "I love sth"))

In [6]: heappush(pq, (2, "I gate sth"))

In [7]: heappop(pq)
Out[7]: (2, 'I gate sth')
```

Here I want heap to return `(2, "I hate sth")` I mean  if there are any duplicates then it should return min item which was inserted first. I know here the items are tuples so 3rd one is obviously small.

But is there any way I can store priority and string separately and the items returned in the order they were inserted if there is a tie.

Thanks

Comment: A workaround might be to create a helper method for adding to the heap, that will insert and increment a counter at the second position of the tuples.

Comment: Yeah that I am thinking to do but is there any other option, like does python allows me to store priority queue as (key, object) where object is not included in the priority calculation.

Comment: Or, instead of using tuples, create your own class for the items in the queue, that will either use just the first element for comparison, or automatically handles said counter.

Answer (score 1):

This property is called stability: if two objects are pushed onto the heap and have the same priority, they are popped in the same order.
The python standard library documentation now answers your question:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes
It provides two solutions, one is to use a 3-tuple (key, insertion_count, value), and the other is to use a new item type `PrioritizedItem`, which ignores the value in the `(key, value)` pair and orders only according to the key. This script shows your example and the relative solution:

```py
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any

@dataclass(order=True)
class PrioritizedItem:
    priority: int
    item: Any=field(compare=False)

pq = []
heappush(pq, (2, "I hate sth"))
heappush(pq, (2, "I love sth"))
heappush(pq, (2, "I gate sth"))
print("PQ items as tuples")
print("popped item:")
print(heappop(pq))

print("=====")
pq_insertion_order = []
heappush(pq_insertion_order, PrioritizedItem(2,"I hate sth"))
heappush(pq_insertion_order, PrioritizedItem(2,"I late sth"))
heappush(pq_insertion_order, PrioritizedItem(2,"I gate sth"))
print("PQ items as PrioritizedItem")
print("popped item:")
print(heappop(pq_insertion_order))
```

Running this script we get:

```
PQ items as tuples
popped item:
(2, 'I gate sth')
=====
PQ items as PrioritizedItem
popped item:
PrioritizedItem(priority=2, item='I hate sth')
```

Since heaps are stable then with `PrioritizedItem` the problem is solved.
This same approach can be used also with the `queue.PriorityQueue` class. `PriorityQueue` popping an element is the same as `sorted(list(entries))[0]` and since `sorted()` is stable, then using this approach with the `PrioritizedItem` is stable as well.

Answer (score -2):

Use PriorityQueue class - It returns objects in the sequence they were added

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

q=PriorityQueue()

q.put((1,'eat'))
q.put((2,'code1'))
q.put((2,'code2'))
q.put((2,'code3'))
q.put((3,'sleep'))

while(not q.empty()):
    print(q.get())

# Output
# (1, 'eat')
# (2, 'code1')
# (2, 'code2')
# (2, 'code3')
# (3, 'sleep')
```

Comment: that's not correct. if the first value in the item is duplicated, it will then try to sort based on the subsequent value in the item.